# How to save data in db using MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net, authentication, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an ASP.Net MVC 4.0 application which has already Authentication implemented by default. I am able to Register User, Change Password without changing anything in code or DB.

Now I want to create on table called `ProductMaster`. How could I Add, Update and Delete 
record from this table using inbuilt code?

Right now authentication work with e.g.

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount
WebSecurity.CreateAccount
WebSecurity.ChangePassword
```

Please help me because I am very new to MVC 4

Answer (score 0):

Create a new sample ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application and see how it's done.

Go to `New Project` -> `ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application` -> `Internet Application`.

This project uses Forms Authentication and you'll clearly see the flow with regards to both MVC and Forms Authentication / SQL Server.

Comment: I have no question for Forms Authentication, but i have to perform CRUD operation with my tables

Comment: But I think you'll also learn about better use of forms authentication. Anyway, I think the default template also demonstrates about CRUD operations. Also, [Scottgu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) has great blog posts about exactly this topic. You should also remove the `authentication` tag from your question if you're not asking about authentication...

Answer (score 0):

Like Any other .Net Technology, ado.net query (insert), or using Entity Framework